# AWS SES Frankfurt region isn't supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I deploy a `python+Flask` web app with `AWS ElasticBeanstalk` + `S3` also -- everything is in **Frankfurt** region. I want to configure `AWS SES` but it doesn't run in that region. Is that a problem? Could I use AWS services from different regions? What the point with these regions? Or it's better to find the other solution for sending message than AWS SES?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Europe SES runs from Ireland (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ses_region) , if your application is sending a lot of emails, you will reduce latency between your services if you move to Dublin (but you might increase latency for your end users if they are more from Germany)

You might have additional cost also as you will have cross region traffic (amazon does not count intra region traffic so if all your services run from the same region you will not have to pay traffic)

It really depends what will be your usage with emails, if you low to medium email traffic then you'll be fine using the Dublin end point, if you have really high email traffic and its one of your primary usage, you might want to move your app to Dublin

Answer (score 3):

As of Oct 30, 2019, Amazon SES is [now available](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-ses-is-now-available-in-three-additional-aws-regions/) in Frankfurt region as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned now eu-central-1 (Frankfurt) supports SES. Link to announcement:
[Amazon SES is Now Available in Three Additional AWS Regions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-ses-is-now-available-in-three-additional-aws-regions/)